# Pausing Animation in SceneKit

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I loaded into SceneKit a `.usdz` file which has an animation attached to it. I want to stop this animation to play.. but I can't find the right way.

I load the `.usdz` asset file with the following method:

```
func loadIdle() {
        
    let urlfile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "armi_idle", 
                                        ofType: "usdz", 
                                   inDirectory: "Asset.scnassets")!
    let scene = try! SCNScene(url: URL(string: urlfile)!)
        
    guard let findNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "armi_idle", 
                                               recursively: true) 
    else {
        print("err finde idle")
        return
    }
        
    // try to pause, but not work
    findNode.isPaused = true
    // add to main scene
    self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(findNode)
}
```

A picture of the asset:

[image: ass]

Answer (score 0):

Declare the following properties:

```
import SceneKit

@IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!

var notWalking: Bool = true
var animations = [String: CAAnimation]()
var node = SCNNode()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    self.animation()
}
```

Then try the following logic (you need `Idle` and `Walking` files) :

```
fileprivate func loadAnimation(withKey: String, scene: String, id: String) {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: scene, withExtension: "dae")!
    let source = SCNSceneSource(url: url, options: nil)
    
    guard let character = source?.entryWithIdentifier(id, 
                                  withClass: CAAnimation.self) else { return }

    character.fadeInDuration = 0.5
    character.fadeOutDuration = 0.5

    self.animations[withKey] = character
}
```

then:

```
fileprivate func animation() {
    
    let standStill = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Idle")!
    
    for childNode in standStill.rootNode.childNodes {
        self.node.addChildNode(childNode)
    }        
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.node)
    
    self.loadAnimation(withKey: "walking", scene: "art.scnassets/Walking",
                                              id: "Walking-1")
}
```

and then:

```
func playWalking(key: String) {
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addAnimation(animations[key]!, forKey: key)
}
func stopWalking(key: String) {
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.removeAnimation(forKey: key, 
                                             blendOutDuration: 0.75)
}
```

and at last:

```
@IBAction func pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    notWalking ? playWalking(key: "walking") : stopWalking(key: "walking")
    notWalking.toggle()
}
```